# Setting values on NSEntity blows up in iOS 5 but not iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

So I have a method for downloading the urls for images that "skin" my app.  It has been working in iOS 5 for months, I added a new attribute of type string to the entity in my xcdatamodel and it stopped working.  Even if I delete the attribute it still doesn't work.

When I clean xcode and delete the app form the iPad then launch the app.

In iOS 5 I get this error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x1)" and if I follow the stack trace this happens at the point where I call `setValue:forKey:`.

However if I clean and run in iOS 6 this works fine.

```
- (void)fetchSkinWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock failure:(void (^)(void))failureBlock {
    NSString *skin = [self skinName];

    if (skin) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/skin/%@", BASE_URL, skin]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        if (!error) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];

            if (!jsonError) {
                Skin *s = (Skin *)[Skin findFirstObjectByAttribute:@"name" withValue:skin inContext:[AppDelegate moc]];
                if (s == nil) {
                    s = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Skin" inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegate moc]];
                }

                for (NSString * key in json) {
                    /******** THIS IS WHATS BLOWING UP IN iOS 5 *************/
                    [s setValue:[json objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }

                [[AppDelegate moc] save:nil];

                self.selectedSkin = s;
                [self downloadImageAssetsForSkin:self.selectedSkin completionBlock:completionBlock];
                return;
            } else {
                DLog(@"Error parsing JSON:%@", jsonError);
            }
        } else {
            DLog(@"User with Device ID:%@ failed fetch skin with error:%@.", [AppDelegate uniqueID], error);
        }
    }

    failureBlock();
    return;
}
```

`findFirstObjectByAttribute:withValue:inContext` is an addition on NSManaged Object.

```
+ (NSManagedObject *)findFirstObjectByAttribute:(NSString *)attr_name withValue:(id)value inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", attr_name, value];
    fetch.predicate = predicate;
    fetch.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if (results.count > 0) {
        return [results objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Gonna need some code from your `Skin` class.  Specifically, what does `+findFirstObjectByAttribute: withValue: inContext:` do?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps.

Comment: What's your core data stack setup like? Do you just have the one context?

Comment: I can't respond to your comments because I haven't posted enough, but I too ran into the same problem. Unfortunately I located your answer after I found the same solution. Your answer did help me clarify that I wasn't going totally insane. My issue was happening when I would set a property on the entity. I found that it was the first property listed alphabetically. Mine was "asset" which I changed to "name". Then a property "desc" would throw the same error. So I added the attribute "blah" and all works fine in iOS5.1 now. iOS6+ worked the whole time, it was just iOS5.1 that was causing the pr

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bug with core data.

In case anyone else runs into this problem here is my very "brittle" solution.

Removing and adding the entity back did nothing (did not solve it).  However, one of my co-workers added another attribute to the xcdatamodel "foobar" without a dynamic or anything on the data model, and it seems to run fine.  However, if I remove "foobar", the xcdatamodel no longer works again (only for ios5).

Hope that helps anyone that is experiencing this problem.

Also, if you have information on this bug, or a better fix, PLEASE post it.  I would really love a solid understanding of this bug, and a "real" fix.